# ld library search path for non-standard library name

Tags: gcc, linker, ld

I have a shared library named _myname.so instead of libmyname.so (because it is Python interfaced).
I want to link C++ code against this lib.
It works fine if I put it in the current directory and link it using:

```
g++ -o _myother.so myother.o _myname.so ... -shared
```

However, if _myname.so is in an other directory, I have to put the path, and at run-time, the library will be looked into this same path instead of the standard locations (LD_LIBRARY_PATH and so on).

Is there a way I can specify a search-path to ld (like with -L if my library was named libmyname.so), so at runtime _myname.so is searched in standard locations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 2.18 of GNU Binutils a feature was added to `ld` that allows a library to be specified by its exact name.

From the current `ld` man page:

```
  -l namespec
  --library=namespec
      Add the archive or object file specified by namespec to the list of files to link.
      This option may be used any number of times.  If namespec is of the form :filename,
      ld will search the library path for a file called filename, otherwise it will
      search the library path for a file called libnamespec.a.
```

For the original question, the `:filename` form of `namespec` is used like this:

```
g++ -o _myother.so myother.o -L../myname/ -l:_myname.so -shared
```

- The option, `-L../myname/`, adds the path, `../myname/`, to the library search path.  This path should contain the location of `_myname.so` at link time.
- The `-l:_myname.so` option tells `ld` to search for a library with the exact name, `_myname.so`.  The `lib` prefix and `.so` suffix are not added to `_myname.so` when searching.

At run time, the shared library `_myname.so` is searched for in the standard locations.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Unfortunately, I'm stuck with 2.17 for now.